# Add and Remove Class from an Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a masked js in some inputs. I'm using them for telephone masked inputs. The problem is that sometimes phone numbers can be 10 digits or 11 digits. I need to change the class if a checkbox is checked. This is what I have.

This is the mask, the ones with "2" are for 11 digits.

```
$(".phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
$(".cell").mask("(999) 999-9999");
$(".phone2").mask("(999) 9999-9999");
$(".cell2").mask("(999) 9999-9999");
```

This is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="digits" class="digits"/>Check here if you phone numbers have 11 digits (area code included)<br>
```

And this is my jq (is not working, the class is not changing after click):

```
$(function(){
 $('.digits:checked').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        $('.phone').addClass('phone2').removeClass('phone');
        $('.cell').addClass('cell2').removeClass('cell');
    }
 });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V8dhN/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just changing the assigned class will not change the assigned mask, you need to update the plugin with new options.

There is no need to use 2 different classes, you need to reset the mask.

```
$(function () {
    var $els = $('.phone, .cell').mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $('.digits').change(function () {
        $els.unmask();
        if (this.checked) {
            $els.mask("(999) 9999-9999");
        } else {
            $els.mask("(999) 999-9999");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V8dhN/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.` to target element with class `digits`:

```
$('.digits:checked').click(function(){
// ^ here ---
```

Also try to use event delegation if your checkboxes has been added dynamically:

```
$('body').on('click','digits:checked',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        $('.phone').addClass('phone2').removeClass('phone');
        $('.cell').addClass('cell2').removeClass('cell');
    }
});
```

Comment: I add it and still not working, also update the question with the ".". Thanks anyway.

Comment: how does changing the class will affect the already initialized plugin options